# CUDA Dynamic Parallelism error : LNK2001

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda, nvcc

OK, I've switched over from Python to C++ in VS2012 in an effort to get this project rolling once more.  I've run into a lot of roadblocks and headaches getting to know the ins and outs of this.  Here's my latest, most frustrating one and the compile error that goes with it.

```
1>  C:\Users\Karsten Chu\New Google Drive\Research\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Dynamic Parallelism Test\Dynamic Parallelism Test>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o "x64\Debug\Dynamic Parallelism Test.device-link.obj" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\lib\x64" cuda.lib cudart.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib -lcudadevrt  -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -G --machine 64 "x64\Debug\CUDA Test 2.cu.obj" "x64\Debug\CUDA Test.cu.obj" 
1>Dynamic Parallelism Test.device-link.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __fatbinwrap_54_tmpxft_00000634_00000000_8_cuda_device_runtime_cpp1_ii_5f6993ef
1>C:\Users\Karsten Chu\New Google Drive\Research\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Dynamic Parallelism Test\x64\Debug\Dynamic Parallelism Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And my code.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

__global__ void rkf5(double*, int*);
__global__ void k1(double*);

int main2(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int max_length = 5;
    double concs[max_length];
    for (int i=0; i<max_length; i++)
    {
        concs[i]=0;
        //std::cout<<concs[i];
    }

    double *d_concs;
    int *d_max_length;
    size_t size_concs = sizeof(concs);
    size_t size_max_length = sizeof(max_length);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_concs, size_concs);
    cudaMemcpy(d_concs, concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_max_length, size_max_length);
    cudaMemcpy(d_concs, concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    rkf5<<<1,max_length>>>(d_concs, d_max_length);
    cudaMemcpy(concs, d_concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i<max_length; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<concs[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

__global__ void rkf5(double* concs, int* max_length)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    concs[idx]=idx;
    //dim3 threads = dim3(max_length);
    k1<<< 1, *max_length >>>(concs);
}
__global__ void k1(double* concs)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    concs[idx]=0;
}
```

Please help me out here, I've spent so much time Googling this problem and every lead I find has no solution posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command line for compiling and linking:

```
nvcc.exe -dlink -o "x64\Debug\Dynamic Parallelism Test.device-link.obj" 
-Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " 
-L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\lib\x64" 
cuda.lib cudart.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib  
comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib 
odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib -lcudadevrt -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -G 
--machine 64 "x64\Debug\CUDA Test 2.cu.obj" "x64\Debug\CUDA Test.cu.obj"
```

You are trying to link against cudadevrt linux style (`-lcudadevrt`). This will not work on windows, the invoked linker is form VS. Add `cudadevrt.lib` to your linker input like `cudart.lib`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for that catch.  I'm going to try and compile (hyuk) all these trial/error experiences into a post so that people following me don't break their legs in all the same pitfalls as me.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully compiled and run your code by:

1. using the procedure in [Using CUDA dynamic parallelism in Visual Studio 2010](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/199);
2. changing `main2` to `main`;

The program outputs `0123` :-)

Comment: Haha, yea, pardon the silliness with main and main2, I am pretty new to C++ and VS2012, so I do little layman fixes like that to make error messages go away.  Curious, that means that my code isn't reaching the child kernel otherwise it should output 0's.  Thank you for taking the time!